# read dates from multiple excel files with different formats in R

Tags: r, date

I am trying to read dates from different excel files and each of them have the dates stored in different formats (character or date). This is making the date column on each file being read as character "28/02/2020" or as the numeric conversion excel does to the dates "452344" (number of days since 1900)

```
files1 = list.files(pattern="*.xlsx")
df = lapply(files1, read_excel,col_types = "text")
df = do.call(rbind, df)
```

¿How can I make R to read the character type "28/02/2020" and not the "452344" numeric type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For multiple date format in one column I suggest using `lubridate::parse_date_time()` (or any other date converter that converts ambiguous format to NA instead of printing an error message)

I assume your `df` should look something like this:

```
  # A tibble: 6 x 2
  id    date      
  <chr> <chr>     
1 1     43889     
2 2     43889     
3 3     43889     
4 1     28/02/2020
5 2     28/02/2020
6 3     28/02/2020
```

Then you should use this code:

```
library(lubridate)
df <- as.data.frame(df)

df$date2 <- parse_date_time(x = df$date, orders = "d m y") #converts rows like "28/02/2020" to date

df[is.na(df$date2),"date2"] <- as.Date(as.numeric(df[is.na(df$date2),"date"]), origin = "1899-12-30") #converts rows like "43889"
```

R output:

```
  id       date      date2
1  1      43889 2020-02-28
2  2      43889 2020-02-28
3  3      43889 2020-02-28
4  1 28/02/2020 2020-02-28
5  2 28/02/2020 2020-02-28
6  3 28/02/2020 2020-02-28

str(df)

'data.frame':   6 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ id   : chr  "1" "2" "3" "1" ...
 $ date : chr  "43889" "43889" "43889" "28/02/2020" ...
 $ date2: POSIXct, format: "2020-02-28" "2020-02-28" "2020-02-28" "2020-02-28" ...
```

I know it is not the nicest solution but it should work for you as well

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn´t work as some files have the date column in a date format and other files dates are stored as text

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I modified my answer according to the original question. I think readxl can't identify different date formats, but you can convert it after importing